# Scale image in container proportionally to width of page

Tags: html, css

I've found a lot of answers to this question, but none (that I can find) apply to my particular situation.

I have an image in a div that I would like to scale with the width of the page. However, my image is much larger than what you actually see, as I'm using `object-fit: cover` and `object-position` to fit it to the container. I can't find a solution that keeps the image the same while scaling the container (and therefore image) down.

In other words, I would like the container and image to scale *and have the image look the exactly the same*. All the solutions I've found move the image around inside the container when the page width is changed.

**Edit for clarity:** Imagine there's a dot at the very center of the image, and normally that dot is in the very center of the container. In my case (because of object-position I think), the dot moves vertically when the width of the page is changed. I need some way to scale the container down to keep the dot in the same place.

**Edit 2:** Figured it out. Setting the height of the container via `vw` (viewport width) does exactly what I'm looking for. e.g. `height: 10vw;`

Here's the CSS I have at the moment:

```
.container {
  height: 25%; /* This would need to be removed/changed I assume.*/
}

.image {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
  object-position: 100% 80%;
}
```

My container is the full width of the page.

Comment: Instead of an image, create a div of the right size, set the image as background and background-position:cover :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, after a bit more digging I found the answer to my question. The solution was to use `vw` (viewport width) to set the height of my container.

In my case, using `height: 10vw;` on the container does exactly what I'm looking for. The value of that can be adjusted of course depending on how much space you want the container/image to take up.

Answer (score 1):

This seems so obvious to me, I think I didn't get your point.

Is this what you want ? This snippet shows that no matter the size of the picture, it will fit into the container.

**EDIT** Your issue is that your image isn't centered in your container. To do that, you have several options. Here is one using a relative position with a transform. You could also use flexboxes, which are, in my opinion, much better.

```css
.container {
  width: 500px;
  border: 1px solid darkcyan;
  height: 600px;
}

img {
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  position: relative;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <img src="https://placeholdit.co//i/500x250?&bg=cccccc&fc=000000&text=BIG IMAGE">
</div>
```

Comment: No, sorry. I have no problem making the image fill the container. My issue is that the image moves up and down within the container when the width of the page is changed. Imagine there's a dot at the very center of the image, and normally that dot is in the very center of the container. In my case (because of object-position i think), the dot moves vertically when the width of the page is changed.

Answer (score 0):

```css
.image{
    max-width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<img src="https://wallpaperbrowse.com/media/images/750806.jpg" class="image" />
```

To have your image fill the width of it's container, you need the `max-width` property:

```
.image {
    max-width: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can **use `max-width: 100%;`** in style of the `img`.
But **another way** is to use your image as a background of your div with the following style:

```css
    .container {
        background-image:    url(https://maxoffsky.com/word/wp-content/uploads/2014/04/andreasbg.png);
        background-size:     cover; 
        background-repeat:   no-repeat;
        background-position: center center;
        width:70%;
        height:300px;
        margin:0 auto;
    }
```

```html
<div class="container"><div>
```

---

**Update:**
You can run the following demo and change the size of it [here](https://jsfiddle.net/Lzmrjy12/1/)

```css
    .container {
        background-color: black;
        width:70%;
        margin:0 auto;
        padding:20px;
        position:relative;
    }
    
    img{
      position:relative;
      max-width:100%;
    }
    .dot{
      background:yellow;
      width:10px;
      height:10px;
      position:absolute;
      left:50%;
      top:50%;
      transform: translate(-5px,-5px);
      z-index:1;
      border-radius:50%;
    }
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="dot"></div>
  <img src="https://maxoffsky.com/word/wp-content/uploads/2014/04/andreasbg.png">
<div>
```

You can see the yellow dot always (any page sizes) in the center of image and center of the container:

Small page size:
[image]

Large page size
[image]

Comment: Unfortunately doing it this way still has the same problem. I edited my post which may help explain what I'm looking to do.

Comment: @Marok, I updated my answer. You can see the yellow dot in it always in the center of image and center of the container.

Comment: @Marok, You wrote in your question: _The dot moves vertically when the width of the page is changedI need some way to scale the container down to keep the dot in the same place_. You can test my answer [here](https://jsfiddle.net/Lzmrjy12/1/) and change its size and see that the yellow dot always will be the center of the container and image unless you have another request that was not in your question clearly. Anyway I'm happy that your problem resolved.

Comment: @Marok, Also you can test [this version](https://jsfiddle.net/Lzmrjy12/2/) of my answer and change the size of the page. I just changed `width:100%;height:100%;` and removed `padding` from the container CSS in this version.